# JavaFX: ImageView doesn't display large images

Tags: java, image, user-interface, javafx

I've an issue with displaying large images in an JavaFX ImageView. The ImageView simply doesn't show anything.
It works perfectly fine with small images but not with ones with a size around 4,5mb and above.
The images are in TIFF format but have the extension ".jpg" but I can't think of influences in reference to this.

I use following code to display them:

```
public void nextImage(){
    Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Image img = new Image(imgList.getNext().toURI().toString(), true);
            imageView.setFitWidth(300);
            imageView.setPreserveRatio(true);
            imageView.setCache(true);
            imageView.setImage(img);
            if (imgList.atEnd()){
                nextButton.setDisable(true);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

I've already checked if any errors occuring by using **img.isError()** and **img.getException()**. But unfortunately, there are no errors.

Comment: What do you mean with "it's a Tiff"? Have you simply changed the extension to jpg? If so, you have to know that the class Image is not fully compatible to Tiff images. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/image/Image.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JavaFX doesn't automagically support TIFF by renaming the image file to JPG. These are the [supported formats](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/image/Image.html):

- BMP
- GIF
- JPEG
- PNG